# Optimize an external function with Pyomo (Python)

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I want to optimize an external function that has been written in EES software (Engineering Equations Solver) using Python. To achieve this, I have created a simple code that establishes a connection between EES and Python and performs the optimization.

the code is as follows:

```
from EESConnect import EESConnector
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory


model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Define the decision variable and bound
model.x = pyo.Var(bounds=(-5,5))
x = model.x

# Define the objective function
def my_function(x):
    with EESConnector() as ees:
        # Load the EES file with the objective function
        ees.ees_file_path = 'C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Optimization/Opt.EES'
        # Calculate the values of the objective function
        func = ees.calculate([x])
        return func

# Define the optimization problem
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule= my_function(x), sense=minimize)
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='E:/Py/ipopt/bin/ipopt.exe')
opt.solve(model)

print('x=', value(model.x))
```

However, the aforementioned code appears to be malfunctioning as it seems that Python requires an explicit objective function. The issue seems to stem from the following line of code: `func = ees.calculate([x])`. It gets stuck at that line. It appears that Python tries to put `x` into that function, but EES doesn't accept `x`; it only accepts numeric values. Therefore, it appears that Python necessitates accessing an explicit function, but it couldn't.

I am uncertain, but it seems that we need to tell Python that an explicit objective function is unavailable. Instead, we need to input values into EES software for numerical calculations and retrieve the numerical output. We can then proceed with the optimization process in this manner.

Can anyone assist me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do isn't possible...  Perhaps there is another way.

The "job" of pyomo is to formulate a math model and hand the whole thing over to a solver, so it isn't possible to have some externally referenced function.  The objective function must be a legal pyomo expression to make this happen.  If you reference a function in your code with a `rule=` statement, the return value of that function must be a legal pyomo expression.

So, I think you have 2 options:  First, you could spend some effort to re-construct the function of interest inside of your model, assuming that it can be expressed legally and with pyomo variables.  Or, you could switch frameworks to something that can use an arbitrary function reference for the objective and work with that.  I believe `scipy.optimize` can do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please provide guidance on how to implement the second option for the objective in my code? I am interested in using either Scipy or any other library that you recommend, and would appreciate your help in modifying the code for this purpose.

Comment: well, I'm not super experienced with scipy.optimize, but...  Why don't you start by reading the dox and looking at examples, then try your hand with a "toy problem" by optimizing (max or min) of some goofy polynomial that you make up over a particular interval.  Plot it....see if the answer passes the "giggle test" and then transition to your real function of interest.  If you get stuck, re-post with the code that isn't working and somebody will step in

Comment: I thought it was straightforward. Sure, I'll give it a try. Thank you.